# How to start Sublime Text 3 with no file loaded

Tags: file, session, sublimetext3, loaded

I'm using Windows machine. I have a humongous file that I opened using Sublime Text 3 editor, that caused a freeze. I decided to kill sublime from the Task Manager. Now, every time I start ST it loads all files from previous session including the huge file and causes to freeze again!

How can I start ST without loading any file, put keep the project?